# Error Opening CrystalReport viewer

Tags: sql-server-2005, crystal-reports, sql-server-2005-express

I have this problem which I am trying to debug for a lot of time.

The setup is like this:

i. The application is a Windows application developed using VS2005, .net 2.0.

ii. I use the Cyrstal reports component Crystal Report Viewer and dynamically display various reports in the same form.

iii. The db is SQLSERVER Express 2005 and situated on a different machine.

When I run the application on the db server, I am able to view the report. However, when I run the application on a different machine which is connected to the above dbServer, I get an error. ( I dont get this error on my dev setup)

Source: CrystakReprotViewer.CS:SendDBLogonForReport() Details:Logon failed.
Details: ADO Error Code: 0x
Source: Microsoft OLE DB Provider for SQL Server
Description: [DBNETLIB][ConnectionOpen (Invalid Instance()).]Invalid connection.
SQL State: 08001
Native Error: 
Error in File C:\DOCUME~1\admin\LOCALS~1\Temp\ActionPoints {52820D22-199C-4D46-A76B-70A55D9F54D5}.rpt:
Unable to connect: incorrect log on parameters.    at CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.Controllers.DatabaseControllerClass.SetTableLocation(ISCRTable CurTable, ISCRTable NewTable)
   at CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.Table.set_Location(String value)
   at Trivalve.UI.Client.Reports.CrystalViewer.CrystalReportViewer.SetDBLogonForReport(ConnectionInfo connectionInfo, ReportDocument reportDocument) in D:\Ramjee\Work\Projects\Trivalve\Trivalve\src\tfssetup\2008\Trivalve_2008\Trivalve\Reports\CrystalViewer\CrystalReportViewer.cs:line 127 rptcontrollers.dll SetTableLocation

For more information, see Help and Support Center at http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/events.asp.

Thanks,
Ramjee

Comment: Hi,
i'm running into a very similar problem here. Although the Program is written in VB6. I can connect via SQLNCLI to the DB on a different machine to read an write data. As soon as i try to open a Crystal Report, i get an error "Logon failed." [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][DBNETLIB]ConnectionOpen ... 

Have you had any success in fixing this issue for you?

Comment: No success with this. We had to format the machine for a different reason, haven't seen it after that. Did you have any success?

Answer (score 2):

Use `datasource=servername or ip address\instance name if available,port number`

Default port number is `1433` or `1434`

My problem was solved with this. Posting for the use of others.

Answer (score 1):

If this is a standard installation of SQL Server Express, bear in mind that the only connection method installed  by default is shared memory, and is only available on the server -- you would need to enable another connection protocol such as Named pipes or TCP/IP. To turn networking on, Use SQL Server Configuration Manager to enable relevant protocols and start SQL Browser.

Answer (score 0):

It's telling you exactly what's wrong.

> Details:Logon failed.

Great, we can't logon.

> (Invalid Instance()).]Invalid
>   connection.

Okay.  I bet we have "localhost" as part of the instance name in my connection string.  Since I'm no longer on the "localhost", this obviously won't work.  Let's try there first.  Then perhaps it's the credentials that I'm using to query my database.  Usually what I do is create a RO user that can only do selects on my db and use that for CR.  If none of these are getting me close, let's try making sure that [remote connections are enabled for SQLEXPRESS](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/914277)

> Unable to connect: incorrect log on
>   parameters.

Ok it's definitely a connection issue.

Comment: I tried all these, and failed. I know something to do with connection but not sure what.